# Choosing which full-form GroupBox displays in designer in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I've inherited a large Visual Basic project that has a number of "frames" (obviously, it came from Visual Basic 6.0) which are now GroupBoxes. They all cover the entire form. The program chooses which one to display during execution. That all works fine.

Is there a way to switch between them for display in Visual Studio designer? Now it's displaying only the last one added, and I have to go to the code rather than Toolbox to make changes to all the ones behind the top one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have multiple GroupBoxes that are obscured by each other?

You can try this and see if it suits you.

In VS, to go Tools-->Options.  Expand the Environment drop down and select Keyboard.  In the "Show Commands Containing" text box type "BringToFront."  Make sure that "Format.BringToFront" is selected in the listbox underneath.

In the "Use New Shortcut in" drop down box, select Windows Forms Designer.  Now, choose a keyboard shortcut that you want to use and type it in the "Press Shortcut Keys" textbox.  I used Ctrl+Alt+B.  Lastly, hit Assign and the OK to exit the dialog box.

You now have a shortcut to bring a selected control to the front of the form.

Open the form with the GroupBoxes in VS, then View-->Other Windows-->Document Outline.  From there you can see every control on the form in a tree view structure.  Select the GroupBox you want to work on, and then click on the tab that the form is shown in to put the focus back on the form without changing the selected GroupBox.  Now hit your shortcut to bring the GroupBox to the front so you can work on it.

I tested this with something simple (two text boxes behind each other) and it worked, so hopefully it works for you too.

Answer (score 0):

Over in the properties window there's a drop down with all the controls on the form. They should be in there.

Comment: They are, but even selecting one doesn't pop it to the front in the designer.